# Wix React-Native-Navigation V2 RN57 Support

Tags: react-native, navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

**android/build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support' && requested.name != 'multidex') {
            details.useVersion "${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'XProj1'

include ':app'

include ':react-native-navigation'
project(':react-native-navigation').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-navigation/lib/android/app/')
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xproj1"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        missingDimensionStrategy "RNN.reactNativeVersion", "reactNative57"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support' && requested.name != 'multidex') {
            details.useVersion "${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':react-native-navigation')
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3"
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xproj1">
    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.xproj1;

//import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationActivity;

public class MainActivity extends NavigationActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
//    @Override
//    protected String getMainComponentName() {
//        return "XProj1";
//    }
}
```

**MainApplication.java**

```
package com.xproj1;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;
import com.reactnativenavigation.react.NavigationReactNativeHost;
import com.reactnativenavigation.react.ReactGateway;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication{
  @Override
  protected ReactGateway createReactGateway() {
    ReactNativeHost host = new NavigationReactNativeHost(this, isDebug(), createAdditionalReactPackages()) {
      @Override
      protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
        return "index";
      }
    };
    return new ReactGateway(this, isDebug(), host);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isDebug() {
    return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
  }

  protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    // Add additional packages you require here
    // No need to add RnnPackage and MainReactPackage
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            // eg. new VectorIconsPackage()
    );
  }

  @Override
  public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
    return getPackages();
  }
}
```

Wix 'React-Native-Navigation' V2 is not supporting for RN 57. I have tried all the ways from this PR [PR for RN 57 Support](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/pull/3851). Still Facing Issues. Can anyone write a quick Medium Post on how to Integrate Navigation with RN 57 support.

Answer (score 1):

1. Need both maven for react-native and jitpack **android/build.gradle**

   ```
   allprojects {
     repositories {
          mavenLocal()
          mavenCentral()
          google()
          jcenter()
     maven 
      { url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"}
      maven 
      { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
     }
   }
   ```
2. **Ignore other RNN flavors** 
   in end of **android/build.gradle**
   add below mention code.

   ```
     subprojects { subproject ->
        afterEvaluate {
        if ((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || 
       subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
       android {
           variantFilter { variant ->
               def names = variant.flavors*.name
               if (names.contains("reactNative51") || 
             names.contains("reactNative55")) {
                   setIgnore(true)
               }
           }
         }
       }
    }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a yarn add https://github.com/leonardoballand/react-native-navigation-rn57.git and you're good to go, just follow the Wix library instructions.

Comment: Ran into the same issue. Execution failed for task ':react-native-navigation:compileReactNative57DebugJavaWithJavac'.

Comment: sorry but your solution doesnt work i still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run `react-native-navigation@^2.1.2` along with `react-native@^0.57.5` & `react@16.6.1`.

The only difference that I could spot is that I added the [RNN flavors configuration](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing?id=_82-ignore-other-rnn-flavors) even though it's not highlighted as a mandatory step in the official documentation.

**`app/build.gradle`**

```
subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate {
        if ((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                variantFilter { variant ->
                    def names = variant.flavors*.name
                    if (names.contains("reactNative51") || names.contains("reactNative55") || names.contains("reactNative56")) {
                        setIgnore(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```